# haproxy "no server available" but backends are reachable

Tags: linux, centos, haproxy

I've got haproxy serving two backends for my servers with this configuration:

```
frontend a_prod
    maxconn     500000
    bind        0.0.0.0:1234
    mode        tcp
    option      tcplog
    log         global
    default_backend a_prod_backends

backend a_prod_backends
    balance     source
    mode        http
    option      httplog
    server      a_prod_srv1   42.X.X.X:8310 check port 1234 
    server      a_prod_srv2   172.X.X.X:8310  check port 1234 backup
```

Im trying to understand what is meant when haproxy reports

`haproxy[4860]: backend a_prod_backends has no server available!`

but I can telnet to and traceroute to the backend servers just fine.
Is my configuration poorly done, or is haproxy tell me there is something I am missing?

Comment: You seem to be doing TCP on the front end, but HTTP on the backend. I'm not sure if that's a valid/supported configuration. I'd say pick one or the other and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I've corrected the error (making it all TCP) but the alert still happens.